# Every day or two, the CPU VM receives up to 250% load for several hours

Tags: apache2, mysql, cpu, phpmyadmin, nodejs

The load during the day does not exceed 5%, and these bursts have nothing to do with our side. I use Google Compute Engine f1-micro (virtual machine).

[image]

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- RAM: 600 MB
- CPU: 2 core Haswell

Software:

- Apache,
- Node.js,
- MySQL,
- phpMyAdmin.

Comment: This could be the result of `mlocate` indexing the files on your server. Use `sudo dpkg -l mlocate` to see if it's installed. If it is *and you don't use it*, then you can remove the package with: `sudo apt purge mlocate` 

Comment: As I understand it, it is not active, but thanks for the help. Now I'll try to turn on load monitoring and logging, let's see what kind of monster lives in the bowels of the server.

Comment: if you host a site on that box, then be sure to check access/error log, it may be only Google or other crawlers are attacking and trying to index your site :)

Comment: We have a small Discord bot. But my google virtual machines were stuck beforee installing it. And they continue to do the same now.

Comment: If it is on a very regular schedule, ask the cloud provider if some maintenance happens at that regular time.

Answer (score 0):

you have to see inside OS (ubuntu) and dig there to see what is called. Each day for examlpe `cron` calls are called for bunch of sys and some other software that you run on your box, so I suggest to look there

you can take a look if you `ls -a /etc/cron.daily`, I have this one:

```
root@drvo:/# ll /etc/cron.daily/
total 60K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Feb 15 12:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 120 root root  12K Feb 15 12:43 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  376 Jun  2  2020 apport*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1.5K Aug 11  2020 apt-compat*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1.1K Jun 27  2020 dpkg*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  377 Sep 10 18:15 logrotate*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1.1K Jul  5  2020 man-db*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1.4K Apr  2  2020 ntp*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  102 Feb 13  2020 .placeholder
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  349 Apr  9  2019 quota*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1007 Feb 23  2020 rkhunter*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  286 Aug 11  2020 roundcube-core*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1.5K Oct 15  2018 webalizer*
```

Comment: I only have two lines there) Thanks for trying to help!